# add custom text to facebook share popup

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am trying to do this:

Mr. Testman clicks on facebook share button on my page. it pops up and shows an empty field where Mr. Testman can write his own text and hits on share button. But sometimes Mr. Testman does not have time to write his text, so he wishes there would be a default text like `I like this and wanted to share with you guys`.

How can I add this custom text as a default share text?

sharer.php is no londer supported by facebook, i dont see any settings for this in docs.

Comment: That would be a violation of Platform Policies – you are not allowed to pre-fill _anything_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bad news, you can't. The share dialog and the share button are triggered by the user, that's why you don't need to create an app and ask for any permissions, because the user has full control of what his sharing.

The only way to do that is creating an app, ask users for **publish_actions**  permission and then do a `POST` to the `graph api`:

```
POST graph.facebook.com
  /{user-id}/feed?
    message={message}&
    access_token={access-token}
```

You can read more about it[here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#publishing)

Comment: Even in that case, Platform Policies forbid pre-filling anything.

Comment: Seriously? I thought that you could post "anything" on behalf of the user.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#integration: _“2. You must not pre-fill any of the fields associated with the following products, unless the user manually generated the content earlier in the workflow: […]”_ – and “manually generated” does _not_ mean that they simply submitted a form with pre-filled data, they must _type in_ all of (text) the content themselves.